# AsyncTask Calling itself multiple Times

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I have this Asynctask which working perfectly except it calls `doInBackground` multiple time.

I'm calling a `Broadcastreceiver` from this `AsyncTask` the `Broadcastreceiver` calls `Service` the service executes some background works
so its calls the Broadcastreceiver three times 
why is that ?
any ideas?

> hint : `onreceive` in `logcat` refers to the `onReceive` method in `myBroadCastReceiver` and `onCommandStart` refers to `myService`

UploadFileAsync.java:

```
public class UploadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    private String sourceFileUri, link, spec, username, title, abstract_, desc;
    private Intent intent;
    private Context ctx;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    private NotificationManager mNotifyManager;

    public UploadFileAsync(Intent intent, String sourceFileUri, Context ctx) {
        this.intent = intent;
        this.sourceFileUri = sourceFileUri;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    private void prepareParams() {
        this.title = intent.getExtras().getString("title");
        this.username = intent.getExtras().getString("username");
        this.abstract_ = intent.getExtras().getString("abstract");
        this.link = intent.getExtras().getString("link");
        this.spec = intent.getExtras().getString("spec");
        this.desc = intent.getExtras().getString("desc");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.e("doInBackground", "===========================");
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
            if (sourceFile.isFile()) {
                try {
                    String upLoadServerUri = Constants.UPLOAD_FILE_TO_SERVER;
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                            sourceFile);
                    URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setUseCaches(false);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE",
                            "multipart/form-data");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                            "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("masharee3", sourceFileUri);
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"masharee3\";filename=\""
                            + sourceFileUri + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    while (bytesRead > 0) {
                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math
                                .min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,
                                bufferSize);
                    }
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                            + lineEnd);
                    serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    String serverResponseMessage = conn
                            .getResponseMessage();
                    if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                        Log.e("server response = 200", " "+serverResponseMessage);
                        mBuilder.setContentText(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.publish_completed))
                                .setProgress(0, 0, false);
                        mNotifyManager.notify(Constants.NOT_ID, mBuilder.build());
                        Intent i = new Intent()
                                .putExtra("username", username)
                                .putExtra("title", title)
                                .putExtra("spec", spec)
                                .putExtra("link", link)
                                .putExtra("desc", desc)
                                .putExtra("abstract", abstract_);
                        i.setAction("com.omaralmrsomi.masharee3app.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_NOTIFICATION");
                        ctx.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(i);
                    } else {
                        mBuilder.setContentText(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.publish_failed))
                                .setProgress(0, 0, false);
                        mNotifyManager.notify(Constants.NOT_ID, mBuilder.build());
                    }
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return String.valueOf(serverResponseCode);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.e("onPostExecute", "===========================");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.e("onPreExecute", "============================");
        prepareParams();
        mNotifyManager =
                (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.publishing_project))
                .setContentText(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.publishing))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat);
        mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, true);
        mNotifyManager.notify(Constants.NOT_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

my LogCAT

```
09-13 22:56:40.271 9505-9505/com.omaralmrsomi.masharee3app E/onPreExecute: ============================
09-13 22:56:40.355 9505-9653/com.omaralmrsomi.masharee3app E/doInBackground: ===========================
09-13 22:56:41.064 9505-9653/com.omaralmrsomi.masharee3app E/server response = 200:  OK
09-13 22:56:41.078 9505-9505/com.omaralmrsomi.masharee3app E/onRecevie: ======--=========
09-13 22:56:41.090 9505-9505/com.omaralmrsomi.masharee3app E/onRecevie: ======--=========
09-13 22:56:41.102 9505-9505/com.omaralmrsomi.masharee3app E/onRecevie: ======--=========
09-13 22:56:41.110 9505-9505/com.omaralmrsomi.masharee3app E/oncommandstart: ============
09-13 22:56:41.110 9505-9505/com.omaralmrsomi.masharee3app E/getData not null: ===-=-
09-13 22:56:41.110 9505-9505/com.omaralmrsomi.masharee3app E/uploadToServer: =-=-=
09-13 22:56:41.124 9505-9505/com.omaralmrsomi.masharee3app E/oncommandstart: ============
09-13 22:56:41.124 9505-9505/com.omaralmrsomi.masharee3app E/getData not null: ===-=-
09-13 22:56:41.124 9505-9505/com.omaralmrsomi.masharee3app E/uploadToServer: =-=-=
09-13 22:56:41.134 9505-9505/com.omaralmrsomi.masharee3app E/oncommandstart: ============
09-13 22:56:41.134 9505-9505/com.omaralmrsomi.masharee3app E/getData not null: ===-=-
09-13 22:56:41.134 9505-9505/com.omaralmrsomi.masharee3app E/uploadToServer: =-=-=
09-13 22:56:41.164 9505-9505/com.omaralmrsomi.masharee3app E/onPostExecute: ===========================
```

**Update :**

this is how i call AsyncTask :

```
  create_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckConnection chk = new CheckConnection(getApplicationContext(), NewPost.this);
                if (chk.testConnection()) {
                    if ((!inputtitle.getText().toString().equals("")) && (!inputAbstract.getText().toString().equals("")) && (!inputdesc.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                        if (state == 1) {
                            PdfPathHolder = FilePath.getPath(NewPost.this, uri);
                            link = Constants.SERVER_LINK + "" + (PdfPathHolder != null ? PdfPathHolder.substring(PdfPathHolder.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) : null);
                            username = userName.getText().toString();
                            title = inputtitle.getText().toString();
                            desc = inputdesc.getText().toString();
                            abstract_ = inputAbstract.getText().toString();
                            new_spec = check();
                            Intent i = new Intent()
                                    .putExtra("username", username)
                                    .putExtra("title", title)
                                    .putExtra("spec", new_spec)
                                    .putExtra("link", link)
                                    .putExtra("desc", desc)
                                    .putExtra("abstract", abstract_);
                            new UploadFileAsync(i, PdfPathHolder, NewPost.this).execute("");
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(NewPost.this, please_select_afile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(NewPost.this, one, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(NewPost.this, bad_internet, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you show how you are executing this asynctask?

Comment: have you registered three broadcast receivers? or registered the same broadcast receiver three times? because doInBackground in not called multiple times as 'E/server response = 200:  OK' is logged only once @Warlock

Comment: So what happens if the button is pressed 2, 3, 4 ..... n times?

Comment: Then the sequence should be onPreExecute->doInbackground->onPostExecute and repeat the same again. But here it is not the case, Asynctask is executed only once here. Handling multiple clicks is another task @MarkKeen

Comment: Why not move all the Async stuff into a service - flow :  start a service, do the background work, and fire a broadcast back the the activity once its done?

Comment: i haven't registered 3 broadcast-receivers